# how to use apply-like function on data frame? [please see details below]

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a `dataframe` with columns A, B and C.
I want to apply a function on each row of a `dataframe` in which a function will check the value of `row$A` and `row$B` and will update `row$C` based on those values. How can I achieve that?

Example:

```
  A   B  C
1 1  10 10
2 2  20 20
3 NA 30 30
4 NA 40 40
5 5  50 50
```

Now I want to update all rows in C column to B/2 value in that same row if value in A column for that row is `NA`.

So the `dataframe` after changes would look like:

```
  A   B  C
1 1  10 10
2 2  20 20
3 NA 30 15
4 NA 40 20
5 5  50 50
```

I would like to know if this can be done without using a `for` loop.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using `for` loop and it's working. But I want to know how can we do this using one of `apply` functions. I tried using `apply` but I am not sure if I am clear with it. Okay let me try out for some time and I will get back to you soon.

Comment: `apply` is just syntactic sugar for a loop.  Assignment and indexing are vectorised though; that's what you want to use.

Comment: Ohh okay. I think I understood.

Comment: Your question doesn't state what value `C` should take when `A` is not missing.  Should it be left alone (as per my, akrun's answers) or take the value of `B` (as per adomasb's answer)?  Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_data <- within(your_data, C[is.na(A)] <- B[is.na(A)] / 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to update the column by reference (without copying the whole data set when updating the column) could also try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[is.na(A), C := B/2]
dat
#     A  B  C
# 1:  1 10 10
# 2:  2 20 20
# 3: NA 30 15
# 4: NA 40 20
# 5:  5 50 50
```

---

Edit: 
Regarding @aruns comment, checking the address before and after the change implies it was updated by reference still.

```
library(pryr)
address(dat$C)
## [1] "0x2f85a4f0"
setDT(dat)[is.na(A), C := B/2]
address(dat$C)
## [1] "0x2f85a4f0"
```

Comment: +1, Wouldn't this create a warning?. I was playing around with the same code, so that is why I asked.  Though, there was no warning with `setDT(dat)[,C:=as.numeric(C)][is.na(A), C:= B/2]`

Comment: @arun, yes it will, because it will change from `integer` class to `double`. It will still save you copying the whole data set several times while using `<-` and etc. It would be interesting to ask @Arun what happens under hood in this case

Comment: Thanks, for the edit.  So, basically, it would be a `friendly` warning :-)

Comment: @akrun, that would be my guess. I would think Arun wrote it in order to encourage people to be predefine correctly their column types instead of updating them on the fly

Comment: David, precisely. It's to encourage users to be aware of column types better (because it also avoids unnecessary memory allocation - can't be avoided in this case though). But it was Matt who added those warnings in the first place. `data.table` provides detailed warnings/errors even in the slightest places where one could gain performance.

Comment: `data.table` has had `address()` function for a longggg time :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 indx <- is.na(df$A)
 df$C[indx] <- df$B[indx]/2
 df
 #   A  B  C
 #1  1 10 10
 #2  2 20 20
 #3 NA 30 15
 #4 NA 40 20
 #5  5 50 50
```

Answer (score 0):

here is simple example using `library(dplyr)`.

Fictional dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, NA, NA, 2), b=c(10, 20, 50, 50))
```

And you want just those rows where a == NA, therefore you can use `ifelse`:

```
df <- mutate(df, c=ifelse(is.na(a), b/2, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
dat <- transform(dat, C = B / 2 * (i <- is.na(A)) + C * !i)
#    A  B  C
# 1  1 10 10
# 2  2 20 20
# 3 NA 30 15
# 4 NA 40 20
# 5  5 50 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> ddf$C = with(ddf, ifelse(is.na(A), B/2, C))
> 
> ddf
   A  B  C
1  1 10 10
2  2 20 20
3 NA 30 15
4 NA 40 20
5  5 50 50
```